# Why can not add subversion package to my OpenBSD 4.5 machine?

Tags: svn, installation, package, openbsd

I have an OpenBSD 4.5 on a virtual machine. I configured the net and my machine can connect to the OpenBSD FTP repository in Canada (ftp.openbsd.org) correctly. But when I execute this line:

> *pkg_add -v subversion-1.5.5*

Occurs this error:

> *Unknown element: @sha FTlY/mreDMe9nRNLR5+fSIIZWMnivjO0p83rQLSL6F0= in SCALAR(0x7deeda80), at /usr/libdata/perl5/OpenBSD/PackingList.pm line 301,  line 7.*

Does anybody know why I cannot install this package?

**UPDATE 11/12/2009**:
This question has been passed to ServerFault.com, *[link](https://serverfault.com/questions/83788/why-can-not-add-subversion-package-to-my-openbsd-4-5-machine)*.

Comment: You may have better luck asking this question on ServerFault.com, StackOverflow's sister site for system administration issues.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Sorry for not knowing about ServerFault.com.

Comment: What is your PKG_PATH set to? It has to be a 4.5 package set.